# php operands in arrays

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi Guys have the following arrays:

```
 Array
   (
    [0] => Array
      (
        [SERIAL] => 1
        [SCORE_1] => 6.6490630173025
        [SCORE_2] => 13.010510864225
        [SCORE_3] => 7.5543177306323
        [SCORE_4] => 4.1576775823101
        [SCORE_5] => 5.3696604808987
      )

    [1] => Array
      (
        [SERIAL] => 2
        [SCORE_1] => 11.861835175219
        [SCORE_2] => 0
        [SCORE_3] => 1.988806017442
        [SCORE_4] => 0.97387338276326
        [SCORE_5] => 4.0322016758707
    )
```

I need to find the proportion of each element in its array i.e. for example SCORE_1/(SCORE_1+...+SCORE_5) and the serials remain as is. The PHP code looks like this:

```
$r = -1;
$namedDataArray = array();

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
$dataRow = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,null, true,             true, true);
if ((isset($dataRow[$row]['A'])) && ($dataRow[$row]['A'] > '')) {
    ++$r;
    foreach($headingsArray as $columnKey => $columnHeading) {

        if($dataRow[$row][$columnKey]==0){

        $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = 0;

        }elseif($columnHeading=='SERIAL' ){

                $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading]=$dataRow[$row][$columnKey];
            } else {
                $x=(float)1.35;
                $a=pow($dataRow[$row][$columnKey],$x);

                $namedDataArray[$r][$columnHeading] = $a;
            }

        }
  }  
}  



echo '<pre>';

print_r($namedDataArray);

echo '</pre><hr />';
```

I'm still new to php and have been struggling with this one. I used PHPExcel to read the file and raise each element to the power of 1.35 . I've used `$total=array_sum($namedDataArray)` but when I try to divide i.e`$Score= $namedDataArray/$total` it says unsupported operand type.

Answer (score 0):

On this line :

```
$Score= $namedDataArray/$total
```

`$namedDataArray` is an array. PHP doesn't allow you to perform a division with an array, you have to put a number instead, for i.e. `$Score = $namedDataArray[0]['SCORE_1'] / $total`

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually provided a solution to this. You just repeated the error message he already got..

Comment: The author seems to don't understand why the error message is displayed. 'it says unsupported operand type', I don't see something like "Can't divide an array with a number". It's exactly as if you miss the ";" at the end of a line and get tons of errors instead of "You missed the ;".

Comment: Ok I see where we are getting at, so what i need to to loop through the columns, how now do I 'Change' the ['SCORE_*']'s so that they become column index i.e instead of $namedDataArray[0]['SCORE_1] it will be something like $namedDataArray[0][1] e.t.c

Comment: You can do something like `$i = 1; $namedDataArray[0]['SCORE_' . $i];`